# Comparing image in url to image in filesystem in python

Tags: python, image-processing, diff, python-imaging-library, image-comparison

Is there a quick and easy way to do such comparison?

I've found few image compare questions from stackoverflow but none of those actually proved answer for this question.

I have images files in my filesystem and a script that fetches images from urls. I want to check if the image in url is already the same that is on disk. Normally I would load the image in disk and url to a PIL object and use following function I found:

```
def equal(im1, im2):
    return ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox() is None
```

but this doesn't work if you have a image saved to disk with PIL as it gets compressed even if you turn the quality to 100 `im1.save(outfile,quality=100)`.

My code is currently following: 
http://pastebin.com/295kDMsp
but the image always ends up re-saved.

Comment: Use a lossless image format, not JPEG. (But if all you are doing is checking for exact identity, compare image hashes instead.)

Comment: Compare md5 sums of two files

Comment: I tried comparing md5 sums but after I finally found a method to get md5 from a file in url without saving it to a disk they appeared to have diffrent sum. If you have an example on how to compare sums for file in disk and for file in url without saving it to disk please post :)  Saving every file to disk for compare would kill disk I/O as it's going thru 13k of images.

Comment: If the images have the slightest difference, then taking md5 sum is a very worthless idea. There are much better ideas to measure image similarity, I will include one of these later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question's title suggests you have two exact images to compare, and that is trivially done. Now, if you have similar images to compare then that explains why you didn't find a fully satisfactory answer: there is no metric applicable to every problem that gives the expected results (note that expected results varies between applications). One of the problems is that it is hard -- in the sense that there is no common agreement -- to compare images with multiple bands, like color images. To handle that, I will consider the application of a given metric in each band, and the result of that metric will be the lowest resulting value. This assumes the metric has a well established range, like [0, 1], and the maximum value in this range means the images are identical (by the given metric). Conversely, the minimum value means the images are totally different.

So, all I will do here is give you two metrics. One of them is [SSIM](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/) and the other one I will call as NRMSE (a normalization of the root of the mean squared error). I choose to present the second one because it is a very simple method, and it may be enough for your problem.

Let us get started with examples. The images are in this order: f = original image in PNG, g1 = JPEG at 50% quality of `f` (made with `convert f -quality 50 g`), g2 = JPEG 1% quality of `f`, h = "lightened" g2.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Results (rounded):

- NRMSE(f, g1) = 0.96
- NRMSE(f, g2) = 0.88
- NRMSE(f, h) = 0.63
- SSIM(f, g1) = 0.98
- SSIM(f, g2) = 0.81
- SSIM(f, h) = 0.55

In a way, both metrics handled well the modifications but `SSIM` showed to be a more sensible by reporting lower similarities when images were in fact visually distinct, and by reporting a higher value when the images were visually very similar. The next example considers a color image (f = original image, and g = JPEG at 5% quality).

[image] [image]

- NRMSE(f, g) = 0.92
- SSIM(f, g) = 0.61

So, it is up to you to determine what is the metric you prefer and a threshold value for it.

Now, the metrics. What I denominated as NRMSE is simply 1 - [RMSE / (`maxval` - `minval`)]. Where `maxval` is the maximum intensity from the two images being compared, and respectively the same for `minval`. RMSE is given by the square root of MSE: sqrt[(sum(A - B) ** 2) / |A|], where |A| means the number of elements in A. By doing this, the maximum value given by RMSE is `maxval`. If you want to further understand the meaning of MSE in images, see, for example, https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/publications/SPM09.pdf. The metric SSIM (Structural SIMilarity) is more involved, and you can find details in the earlier included link. To easily apply the metrics, consider the following code:

```
import numpy
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

def ssim(im1, im2, window, k=(0.01, 0.03), l=255):
    """See https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/"""
    # Check if the window is smaller than the images.
    for a, b in zip(window.shape, im1.shape):
        if a > b:
            return None, None
    # Values in k must be positive according to the base implementation.
    for ki in k:
        if ki < 0:
            return None, None

    c1 = (k[0] * l) ** 2
    c2 = (k[1] * l) ** 2
    window = window/numpy.sum(window)

    mu1 = fftconvolve(im1, window, mode='valid')
    mu2 = fftconvolve(im2, window, mode='valid')
    mu1_sq = mu1 * mu1
    mu2_sq = mu2 * mu2
    mu1_mu2 = mu1 * mu2
    sigma1_sq = fftconvolve(im1 * im1, window, mode='valid') - mu1_sq
    sigma2_sq = fftconvolve(im2 * im2, window, mode='valid') - mu2_sq
    sigma12 = fftconvolve(im1 * im2, window, mode='valid') - mu1_mu2

    if c1 > 0 and c2 > 0:
        num = (2 * mu1_mu2 + c1) * (2 * sigma12 + c2)
        den = (mu1_sq + mu2_sq + c1) * (sigma1_sq + sigma2_sq + c2)
        ssim_map = num / den
    else:
        num1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + c1
        num2 = 2 * sigma12 + c2
        den1 = mu1_sq + mu2_sq + c1
        den2 = sigma1_sq + sigma2_sq + c2
        ssim_map = numpy.ones(numpy.shape(mu1))
        index = (den1 * den2) > 0
        ssim_map[index] = (num1[index] * num2[index]) / (den1[index] * den2[index])
        index = (den1 != 0) & (den2 == 0)
        ssim_map[index] = num1[index] / den1[index]

    mssim = ssim_map.mean()
    return mssim, ssim_map


def nrmse(im1, im2):
    a, b = im1.shape
    rmse = numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum((im2 - im1) ** 2) / float(a * b))
    max_val = max(numpy.max(im1), numpy.max(im2))
    min_val = min(numpy.min(im1), numpy.min(im2))
    return 1 - (rmse / (max_val - min_val))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from scipy.signal import gaussian
    from PIL import Image

    img1 = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    img2 = Image.open(sys.argv[2])

    if img1.size != img2.size:
        print "Error: images size differ"
        raise SystemExit

    # Create a 2d gaussian for the window parameter
    win = numpy.array([gaussian(11, 1.5)])
    win2d = win * (win.T)

    num_metrics = 2
    sim_index = [2 for _ in xrange(num_metrics)]
    for band1, band2 in zip(img1.split(), img2.split()):
        b1 = numpy.asarray(band1, dtype=numpy.double)
        b2 = numpy.asarray(band2, dtype=numpy.double)
        # SSIM
        res, smap = ssim(b1, b2, win2d)

        m = [res, nrmse(b1, b2)]
        for i in xrange(num_metrics):
            sim_index[i] = min(m[i], sim_index[i])

    print "Result:", sim_index
```

Note that `ssim` refuses to compare images when the given `window` is larger than them. The `window` is typically very small, default is 11x11, so if your images are smaller than that, there is no much "structure" (from the name of the metric) to compare and you should use something else (like the other function `nrmse`). Probably there is a better way to implement `ssim`, since in Matlab this run much faster.

Comment: This answer explains how to use `scikit-image` library's `compare_ssim` method

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207748/3337089

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own comparison - using square difference. You will then set up a threshold, like 95% and if they are that similar, then you don't have to download it. It eliminates the problem of compression

Comment: Do you have any examples (I am personally curious!)

Comment: I tried calculating  root-mean-square difference but that ends up with something like 2000 difference between the histograms of image loaded from url and from filesystem.

Comment: try loading the same image and then change a few pixels to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of [Bartlomiej Lewandowski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13876106/298171)'s suggestion, I would recommend comparing histogram entropy, which is easy and relatively quick to calculate:

```
def histogram_entropy(im):
    """ Calculate the entropy of an images' histogram.
    Used for "smart cropping" in easy-thumbnails;
    see also https://raw.github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/master/easy_thumbnails/utils.py
    """
    if not isinstance(im, Image.Image):
        return 0  # Fall back to a constant entropy.

    histogram = im.histogram()
    hist_ceil = float(sum(histogram))
    histonorm = [histocol / hist_ceil for histocol in histogram]
```

... This function is one that I use in a [auto-square-crop filter](https://github.com/fish2000/django-instakit/blob/master/django_instakit/processors/squarecrop.py) I built — but you can use the entropy value to compare any two images (even of disparate size).

I have other examples of the application of this sort of idea, let me know with a comment if you'd like me to send a specific example your way.

Comment: Well, that function does seem to return something useful. I got value `5.74535571765` from the file in disk and value `4.85352821002` from file read from url. How should I compare these value and when to decide if the files are similiar or not?

Comment: The problem with this histogram comparison is that I can have totally different images (just negate the original, for example) and get the exactly same value.

Comment: @mmgp yes, but in all likelihood that kind of collision wouldn't be an issue in this context.

Comment: @fish2000 my comment was just a simplification about the method not being able to correctly distinguish differences, producing meaningless results in certain cases. This can be the case for any metric, but I was trying to point that this specific one is more susceptible to problems, not trying to offend anyone.

Comment: Are you suppose to take the mean of histonorm?