# Image comparator returns false

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, duplicates

So, I'm using a file sharing app on Android. It creates a duplicate copy which is uploaded to it's server.

**PROBLEM**
The following code works for a duplicate copy I manually create. That is, I long press and copy the file into the same directory with a File Manager. Then my function returns `true`. When it compares the duplicate image due to the app and the original image, I get `false`.

MD5-checksums are different so that is out of the options.

**CODE**

```
    public boolean equals(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
        ByteBuffer buffer1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap1.getHeight()
                * bitmap1.getRowBytes());
        bitmap1.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer1);

        ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap2.getHeight()
                * bitmap2.getRowBytes());
        bitmap2.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer2);

        return Arrays.equals(buffer1.array(), buffer2.array());
    }
```

Here are the images :

Original image - [image: original]

Duplicate image created by the app - [image: duplicate]

My code currently returns false while comparing these two images.
How do I get the code to return true?

Comment: Your problem is not very clear please make is more clear.

Comment: @AliImran Is that better?

Comment: Your this line is confusing `When it compares the duplicate image due to the app and the original image` here what do you mean by saying `due to the app` ?

Comment: @AliImran The third-party app which I use for file sharing creates a copy of the image and uploads it. That is the duplicate image I'm referring to by "due to the app".

Comment: The problem is related to third party app. did try to debug your code? and check the size of `ByteBuffer` as it must be different from original image and this is because the third party app may be using some compression in the original image.

Comment: @AliImran Checked everything. I'm guessing the EXIF information is modified. However, I can't use the metadata comparison for finding duplicates since it's not a foolproof way. Some images might lack certain tags.

I'm guessing the third party app compresses it in someway.

Comment: @AliImran you are confusing him, stop with that. This is a basic matter, which is due to the use of lossy compression.

Comment: @mmgp Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to artefacts created by JPEG compression, if you can always keep the images in PNG then your problem is most likely solved. If you can't do that, then you need a better algorithm to compare the images. This is exactly the same problem discussed at [Comparing image in url to image in filesystem in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875989/comparing-image-in-url-to-image-in-filesystem-in-python/13884956#13884956)

For instance, running the algorithms mentioned in the earlier discussion, we get a similarity of more than 99%. With that similarity value, you can say the images are the same.

Comment: Say jpegs have widely been used. If I convert the original and duplicate to .png formats and then compare their checksums, will they be the same? Or if I compare them with the code I've shown will it return true?

Comment: No, the checksums will be different. You have to start and end with PNG, if you mix JPEG in the middle then you are using lossy compression.

Comment: Note that the metric named as NRMSE in the linked discussion is very easy to implement, you could consider using it.

Comment: I'm new to image processing. So, could you link me to the basics so that I understand the contents of the link you've posted?

Comment: @mgmp Couldn't I just compare the pixels in different areas of the picture?

Comment: @Torcellite both methods are effectively comparing the pixels, what else could they be doing ? To point you anywhere, I need to better understand what are your doubts.

Comment: @mgmp Could you tell me if there's a way to compare an image with lossy compression? I'm not really able to understand the contents of the link you've posted.
Also, if there's a resized version of a .png file, will the code I've used above work?

Comment: The linked discussion is comparing images, which in this case were lossy compressed. So, yes, there are ways to do it, and you have been pointed to two of them (a complex one, and a simple one). What do you mean by having a resized image ? Do you want to compare resized and non-resized images ? The linked discussion includes a pretty good link related to MSE (https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/publications/SPM09.pdf) which is very close to the thing named as NRMSE on the discussion.

Comment: By "resized images", I mean this - Say I have an 80kb .png file, I share it via the app. It creats a duplicate which is around 16kb. Can I compare it by using pixel to pixel comparison?

Comment: If the images have the same dimensions (width x height) then you can directly use the metrics mentioned earlier. This doesn't complicate the comparison in any way.