# Python image comparison regardless of size

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images, i want a response (true or false) to know if they are different.
The images are not of the same size.

Comment: `return True` - there you go. (If they are not the same size, they are always different - I presume you have a different definition of *different* you will need to explain to us).

Comment: Does "the same" mean that one image is a crop of the other, one is a scaled version of the other, one has a different colorspace or color depth than the other, one is a different format (jpg, png, etc) than the other, or something else?

Comment: I mean that one image can be the same resized. For the format they are images understanded by PIL, in fact they are PIL objects

Comment: Include some of the actual images that you want to compare. Plus, tagging this as python is totally irrelevant, as the task to be performed is much more relevant and language agnostic.

Comment: @mmgp Not totally irrelevant; if anyone decides to do a code example for him, know which language and libraries he's using helps out.  A `PIL` tag might not be a bad idea in that case though...

Comment: @sr2222 twice irrelevant now. Would you prefer a barely working solution in pure Python+PIL or a more robust method that is clear enough that can written in Python ? Even if it uses, let's say scipy and opencv, in place of PIL. The question being asked is not trivial in its general form, and that is the important part to be answered.

Comment: do a search for image fingerprinting solutions.

Comment: @mmgp: LOL! really do you need a sample? take your best pic, take is another time and resize it, take paint and edit it. Now you have your two samples

Comment: @tapioco123 such naiveness shows how you are unaware of the problem you are solving. There are many ways to resize images, be it by varying the sampling methods (which are many), or be it by using different resizing strategies. It is also affected by the file format you use, as it might add compression artifacts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple dummy method: resize the largest image to match the size of the smallest image and compare.

Consider the following images and enumerate them from 1 to 4 respectively:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

To compare two images `i` and `j`, resize the largest of them to the dimensions of the other one using 3-lobed lanczos, which is conveniently available in `PIL` by doing `img1.resize(img2.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)`. Now you proceed to the comparison using for, example, the metrics described at [Comparing image in url to image in filesystem in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875989/comparing-image-in-url-to-image-in-filesystem-in-python/13884956#13884956).

Here are the similarity results using, respectively, the metrics SSIM and NRMSE presented in the linked answer:

Image 1 
    -> 2: [0.98, 0.97]; 
    -> 3: [0.96, 0.98]; 
    -> 4: [0.99, 0.99];

Image 2: 
    -> 3: [0.98, 0.97]; 
    -> 4: [0.98, 0.93];

Image 3: 
    -> 4: [0.97, 0.98].

These values are at max 1, indicating the images are exactly the same according to the metric. So, as you can see, the values are pretty close to 1. All you have to do is pick a threshold near there and return `True` if the result given by a metric is above the threshold, and `False` otherwise.

Comment: If a take a picture having 16:9 or 4:3 dimensions and have to compare it to a square one, I would likely crop it on sides and keep only its center to match a square shape, rather than resizing it (thus stretching/distorting it). However, depending on what you have to achieve, the images sources etc., resizing can still be a better approach.

Answer (score -1):

No method will be perfect, but you can try:

1. Define a sample size defined as a percentage of image size
2. Define the number of samples you want to take
3. Distribute the sample regions across the two images
4. At each sample, average the color values across all the pixels in the sample region
5. For each pair of averaged sample region color values, verify they are within some small margin of error equal
6. Define a threshold for the number of matched samples that balances false negatives and false positives at a level you are comfortable with
7. If the threshold is met, return a result signifying the images match, else return a result signifying they do not

So, say you start with 2 images, sized 100X100 and 200X200, and you decide you want to sample regions at 10% of each dimension, with 4 samples.  You will average and compare:

- x0-9, y0-9 to x0-19, y0-19
- x90-99, y0-9 to x180-199, y0-19
- x0-9, y90-99 to x0-9, y180-199
- x90-99, y90-99 to x180-199, y180-199