# Compare a image with a list Python

Tags: python, image

I have been fighting with a program and I have read many info about use images in python but I did not get my program works.

I am doing a program that recognice a card. I have a "database" of all the cards each one in a different jpg file. So that tried its to compare the card that we want to know with all the possible cards. Then the card that are more similar would be the card that I am looking for. I have tried with several different codes but no one do his job correctlly.

```
def get_card(image1path):
    from PIL import Image
    import math
    import os
    import operator
    __docstring__ = "compare two image files"
    h1 = Image.open(image1path).resize((40,55)).histogram()
    best=99999999
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk("cards"):
        for file in [f for f in files]:
            list=(os.path.join(root, file))
            h2 = Image.open(list).resize((40,55)).histogram()
            rms = math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add, map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2, h1, h2))/len(h1))
            print "RMS = "+str(rms)+"  and the picture is:"+list
            if rms<best:
                best=rms
                card=(os.path.join(file)).split(".")[0]

    return card

image1path="C:\\8d.jpg" #eight of diamonds.
card=get_card(image1path)
print card
```

The problem is that it dont work fine because after the comparation of the RMS of each card with all of them, there are some wrong cards that get best RMS punctuation. So the recogniced card is not the eight of diamonds like t must be.

How must i do it?? If you need that I explain it in other words just say it.

Thank you very much

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875989/comparing-image-in-url-to-image-in-filesystem-in-python/13884956#13884956 for two comparison metrics. They should help you in this task, otherwise include the images you have problem with.

Comment: Since you can't including the image in your question as @mmgp suggests, upload them somewhere and include links to each of them in your message.

Comment: Perhaps you're reducing the images too much for your metric.

Comment: Why did you decide to calculate histogram's RMSE instead of the pairwise intensities ? Performance is not much a excuse here.

Comment: @mmgp can you say me a example about the "pairwise intensities"? I dont know it.

Comment: Here you have all the cards in jpg format: https://mega.co.nz/#!TABCASKR!Fx8raj6VIggE5tEollLrih0rZJl_JuykXxxukPkvi6A  and here the card i want to compare with all of them just to do a demo:
https://mega.co.nz/#!LFY0CaZQ!KxEOpC-t7V4EFzu3TcKCM1B5lSVz9cq5SfLD-jSjtLQ

Comment: @mmgp I have read your post! You did a great work. I have just a problem and it is that the size of the two pictures are different so according to your code it will not work. Anyway I will change your code and see what happends. Then I will post it here, Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1618465 just resize one of them and compare.

Comment: I have already try it and commenting the lines that check the image siza and i get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\prueba2.py", line 73, in <module>
    for band1, band2 in zip(img1.split(), img2.split()):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1497, in split
    if self.im.bands == 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'
Why??

Comment: @user1618465 that is mostly a PIL bug. Add `img1.load()` and `img2.load()` after you open, then retry.

Comment: Thanks @mmgp. But it still doesnt work as it could. I add tose lines of code: <blink>img1.load()
    img2.load()
    resolution = (38,55)
    scaler = Image.ANTIALIAS
    img1=img1.resize(resolution,scaler)
    img2=img1.resize(resolution,scaler)</blink>
But I still get this error and it does not matter wich two pictures compare that the output is always the same: C:\pruebas3.py:52: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return 1 - (rmse / (max_val - min_val))
Result: [1.0, nan]
Thanks again!!!

Comment: @user1618465 can you upload your images somewhere else ? I can't download from that site, it always fails ("Temporary unavailable")

Comment: Mega is down. Sorry. Here you have a new link inside there are the cards in png format jpg format and a capture of a random card that must be compared with the list. Thanks

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/cRxeJ/cards.rar

Comment: @user1618465 I didn't get the error you mention, but I believe it could be caused if `max_val == min_val`, in that case, perform an earlier check and `return 1` (inside the `nrmse` function). But, actually, this method of comparison is bad for your problem, it needs to be a bit more smarter and could be specific for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the images that you are comparing, you actually don't want to use metrics such as `RMSE` and others. The reason is because all the images are similar in an "RMSE-sense", or even for more refined metrics that aren't concerned about the basic relations present in the image. Here are some examples given by yourself:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

The basic relations in your case are: color (which also distinguishes between spades, hearts, diamonds, and clubs cards), and shape measures. So, by detecting the color of the card, the search space is reduced and all that is left is discerning between the numbers at the top of the card. Together with the amount of connected components and euler number the search is further restricted. Now what is left is distinguishing: "9" from "6", "4", queen, or "A"; "3" from "J", "2", "5", or "7"; "8" and "10" are solved, the former due to euler number and the later due to its number of connected components (this all assuming the cards are unique, otherwise you proceed and find the most similar card). The simplest thing to do here, which will likely fail if you add more considerations to your problem, is calculating the Hausdorff distance between each shape remaining.

Here is a simplistic implementation that considers these points and works for all the given input. It expects an image and a directory to look for images to compare. Each step can be improved.

```
import sys
import numpy
from scipy.ndimage import morphology, label, find_objects
from PIL import Image

COLORS = range(4)
RED, GREEN, BLUE, BLACK = COLORS

def card_color(img):
    im = img.load()
    width, height = img.size
    black, blue, green, red = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
            r, g, b = im[x, y]
            if r > 200 and g > 200 and b > 200:
                # "white", ignore
                continue

            if r > 200 and g < 100 and b < 100:
                red += 1
            elif r < 100 and g < 100 and b > 200:
                blue += 1
            elif r < 50 and g < 50 and b < 50:
                black += 1
            elif r < 100 and g > 120 and b < 50: # dark green
                green += 1
    return max(zip((black, blue, green, red), COLORS))

def euler_number(img, conn=4):
    im = img.load()
    width, height = img.size

    c1, c2, c3 = 0, 0, 0
    for x in xrange(width - 1):
        for y in xrange(height - 1):
            s = (im[x,y] + im[x+1,y] + im[x,y+1] + im[x+1,y+1]) / 255
            if s == 1:
                c1 += 1
            elif s == 2:
                if (im[x+1,y] and im[x,y+1]) or (im[x,y] and im[x+1,y+1]):
                    c3 += 1
            elif s == 3:
                c2 += 1
    if conn == 4:
        return (c1 - c2 + 2 * c3) / 4
    else: # 8
        return (c1 - c2 - 2 * c3) / 4

def carefully_binarize(img, color):
    if color == BLACK:
        img = img.convert('L')
    else:
        img = img.split()[color]
    width, height = img.size
    im = numpy.empty((height + 2, width + 2), dtype=numpy.uint8) # Padding
    im.fill(255)
    im[1:-1, 1:-1] = numpy.array(img)
    threshold = im.mean() - im.std()
    im[im <= threshold] = 1
    im[im > threshold] = 0
    # Discard small components.
    lbl, ncc = label(im)
    for i in xrange(1, ncc + 1):
        py, px = numpy.nonzero(lbl == i)
        if len(py) < 30:
            im[lbl == i] = 0
    return Image.fromarray(im * 255)

def discard_bottom(img, k=0.5):
    width, height = img.size
    im = numpy.array(img)
    limit = height * k
    lbl, ncc = label(im)
    for i, oslice in enumerate(find_objects(lbl)):
        srow, scol = oslice
        if srow.stop > limit:
            ncc -= 1
            im[srow.start:srow.stop, scol.start:scol.stop] = 0
    return Image.fromarray(im), ncc

def signature(img):
    # Assumption: a single connected component is present now.
    im = numpy.array(img)
    im = morphology.binary_fill_holes(im)
    im = morphology.binary_dilation(im) - im

    py, px = numpy.nonzero(im)
    return Image.fromarray(im.astype(numpy.uint8)*255), zip(py, px)

def hausdorff(a, b):
    dist = 0
    for ai in a:
        mindist = float('inf')
        for bi in b:
            chess = max(abs(ai[0]-bi[0]), abs(ai[1]-bi[1]))
            if chess < mindist:
                mindist = chess
        if mindist > dist:
            dist = mindist
    return dist

img1 = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('RGB')
dirpath = sys.argv[2]

img1_color = card_color(img1)[1]
img1 = carefully_binarize(img1, img1_color)
img1_top, img1_top_ncc = discard_bottom(img1)
img1_top_en = euler_number(img1_top)

feature = [img1_color, img1_top_ncc, img1_top_en]

match = []
for fname in os.listdir(dirpath):
    try:
        img2 = Image.open(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)).convert('RGB')
    except IOError:
        print "Ignoring", fname
        continue

    if card_color(img2)[1] != feature[0]:
        continue

    img2 = carefully_binarize(img2, feature[0])
    img2_top, ncc = discard_bottom(img2)
    if ncc != feature[1]:
        continue
    en = euler_number(img2_top)
    if en != feature[2]:
        continue

    match.append((img2_top, os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))

if len(match) == 1:
    print "Here is your best match:", match[0][1]
else:
    img1_sig, sig1 = signature(img1_top)
    best_match = float('inf'), None
    for img2, fname in match:
        img2_sig, sig2 = signature(img2)
        dist = hausdorff(sig1, sig2)
        if dist < best_match[0]:
            best_match = dist, fname

    print "Best match:", best_match[1]
```